# Rails is not reloading my models in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, development-environment, reload

- I'm using Rails 3.2.13
- In `development.rb`, I have `config.cache_classes = false`
- The problem occurs when I'm using either Unicorn or Webrick

I have a really weird behavior. Let's say I output something in the logs: `Rails.logger.warn "Hello"`

If I reload the page, I will see "Hello" in the logs. If remove it, it will disappear. But if I put it back again, it does not appear...

Also, a simple `raise "Fail!"` in a model will cause an exception to be raised properly. But if I remove the `raise` and reload the page, it will still raise the exception.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you sure it runs in development environment? Try to output your Rails environment in one of the page to verify if you are not mistakenly in production

Comment: I haven't tested it properly, but I think it only happens for the `Item` model. Within this model, I have global constants and constants referencing other models. Not sure if it's relevant. Another thing is that I'm using Tire, and it has an Item class. But it's namespaced so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got rails-dev-boost as a gem? Seen this cause a similar issue before

Comment: It wasn't caused by the dev-boost gem, but I guess that could have been the case, so I accepted it. Don't remember how I resolved the issue, it's been too long.